# Using gulp it possible to generate a fallback background-image from a svg data-uri?

Tags: css, svg, less, gulp

I have a less icon mixin that reads a small suite of svg icons and outputs the result as a css class with background properties.

For the purposes of my current project it's the most efficient way of working with SVGs. The less mixin also adds in the fallback background-image url, referencing a png.

My build task runner of choice for the project is gulp and when the task is run the resulting example css output follows this pattern:

```
.rss {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-color: #ee802f;
}
.no-svg .rss {
  background-image: url('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme/images/rss.png');
}
.svg .rss {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2250%22%20height%3D%2250%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2050%2050%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20d%3D%22M13.296%2040.908c-2.34%200-4.243-1.89-4.243-4.23%200-2.33%201.902-4.24%204.243-4.24%202.354%200%204.25%201.91%204.25%204.24%200%202.342-1.897%204.23-4.25%204.23zm10.67.033c0-3.992-1.554-7.753-4.37-10.564C16.783%2027.556%2013.037%2026%209.057%2026V19.89c11.603%200%2021.05%209.443%2021.05%2021.055h-6.14v-.002zm11.104-.77c0-14.208-11.555-25.775-25.75-25.775V8.28c17.577%200%2031.883%2014.313%2031.883%2031.89H35.07z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

At that point the png file does not exist.

What I'm looking to achieve is a solution within gulp that will look for each data-url'd svg  and then generate the png fallback image file.
Is something like this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you can't save the svg data into `.svg` files instead of inline them? Life will be 10 times easier.

Comment: One of the functions in the icon mixin is the ability to change a fill value from a default colouring. I'm thinking it takes the headache out of generating multiple iterations of a single svg icon

Comment: so what would that mixin do if you decide to provide a single-color fallback png for the svg?

Comment: Assuming that originally you have to have real svg files, can't you just run something like `gulp-svg2png`? (Also assuming that your Less mixin is something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/5b1b65984b5e16deb767))...  I doubt there's some tool (or anybody is going to write a tool) to "parse CSS for data-uris to convert those back to svg to convert those to png" - you already see how strange this sounds.

Comment: @seven-phases-max your gist is right on the money. I elected to go with gulp-raster for now. The concept was to keep the number of svg files to a minimum, but it was getting messy when I needed multi-color svgs. Ta

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sprites gulp-svgfallback will do the trick, it generates an SVG sprite and a second PNG sprite for IE8 and lower.